# Dovecot: Relative home directory paths not supported

Tags: email, dovecot

This is my first time setting up an email sever, and have gone with Dovecot for the IMAP side. I've been following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-email-server-with-dovecot-dynamic-maildirs-and-lmtp) tutorial.

When I try to login to the server, this is printed to the error log:

```
Apr 16 21:39:40 neonorb dovecot: imap(website@test.neonorb.com): Error: Relative home directory paths not supported: 0
Apr 16 21:39:40 neonorb dovecot: imap(website@test.neonorb.com): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
Apr 16 21:39:41 neonorb dovecot: imap(website@test.neonorb.com): Error: Relative home directory paths not supported: 0
Apr 16 21:39:41 neonorb dovecot: imap(website@test.neonorb.com): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

I've looked around, and this appears to be a "feature" that was never supported, it just never gave an error message.

I've looked through the comments of the tutorial, and other people were having this issue, they suggested removing the `'/home/mailboxes/home/'||maildir as home,` part, but this just caused another error:

```
Apr 16 21:45:36 neonorb dovecot: imap(website@test.neonorb.com): Error: User initialization failed: Initializing mail storage from mail_location setting failed: Ambiguous mail location setting, don't know what to do with it: 0 (try prefixing it with mbox: or maildir:)
Apr 16 21:45:36 neonorb dovecot: imap(website@test.neonorb.com): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
Apr 16 21:45:37 neonorb dovecot: imap(website@test.neonorb.com): Error: User initialization failed: Initializing mail storage from mail_location setting failed: Ambiguous mail location setting, don't know what to do with it: 0 (try prefixing it with mbox: or maildir:)
Apr 16 21:45:37 neonorb dovecot: imap(website@test.neonorb.com): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

I've been fiddling around with the config files, but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Please provide from `sudo psql -U mailreader -d mail` the results of `SELECT email, maildir FROM users ;`

Comment: email: website@test.neonorb.com, maildir: website

Answer (score 2):

It appears dovecot is finding the mail directory location.  However it needs to know which type of delivery to use.  Your maildir entries should be prefixed with either `mbox:`, `maildir` or another supported type.  I prefer `maildir:`.

Alternatively add back the mailbox location:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

or use the username to set the location using your preferred directory in place of `/home`:

```
mail_location = maildir:/home/%u/Maildir
```

Comment: I added the first option you suggested in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf` and I got the same "ambiguous mail location" error I mentioned at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Ah, the DO tutorial removed the call to load the stuff in `conf.d/` so that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I added these two lines (from the DO tutorial) to my `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`:

```
mail_home = /home/mailboxes/home/
mail_location = maildir:/home/mailboxes/maildir/
```

I also removed the same things from the SQL query from `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf`.

And now it works!

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` set `user_query`:

```
user_query = SELECT CONCAT('/var/mail/virtual/',maildir) AS home, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u'
```

Where `/var/mail/virtual/` is top directory for maildirs.